# Running logon scripts with the standard user access token?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, uac

I have a powershell script which executes after I logon to my account. This is done by a group policy logon script.

Because I am in the Administrator group this script is run with elevated rights which I don't want. I want it to run without the elevated rights and run it with the standard user access token. Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

I need to have the script run with UAC virtualization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Failing a more elegant solution, I suppose you could write a logon script that adds an entry into the RunOnce key so that Explorer will run the powershell.  You'd probably need to make the logon script synchronous, to avoid a race condition.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for your alternative but I need to know if it's possible with a group policy. In the meantime I already use a other alternative: a scheduled task, but it also works from a batch file in my startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -l option of [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to launch your powershell script.

Comment: I tried your option but it doesn't give me the expected results. The -l option does run it without administrator rights but not with UAC virtualization.